# How to scale Curve Profile Object with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I'm using Geometry Nodes to make some cables and I can't find a way to scale the 'radius' of the curve when the profile is another Curve object instead of a curve primitive.

[image]

With the curve primitive as the profile you can set the radius directly in that node, but that's not an option on the Object Info node and the Scale Elements one doesn't work with Curves so how should I go about this?

I know I can manually scale the curve profile in edit mode but ideally I'd like to only have 1 of these objects that I can use with different sized cables. Is it possible to scale it within the geometry nodes set up?

Comment: Use the set curve radius node before the curve to mesh node

Comment: That works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the radius of the curve (**not** profile curve). use the *set curve radius* node.

---

the reason why the *scale elements* doesn't work is because it only works on meshes. use *transform geometry* node to work on everything.

---

if you want to just scale the islands, and they are curves, you could

- take the average position of each curves
- subtract it from the position
- scale the position
- add the average position
- set this as the position.

(to take the average position just use the *evaluate on domain* node set to spline)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can either add a `curve to mesh node` and then a `mesh to curve node` after the object info node and then add a `scale elements node` in between those two nodes and set its domain to edge to scale each island individually.
2. Or you can add a `set curve radius node` after the geometry output of the group input node to scale all of the islands together.

[image]